# Ignore an Ebean Version in certain situations

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm using a Version field with Ebean, in Play Framework 2.2, but in certain situations I would actually rather have the version of an object not be updated. Is this at all possible?

So someone has an account on my website and they're looking at a post of another user. If the user updates that post, it's not automatically reloaded in the frontend. Please don't suggest I do this to solve the problem, I can't do it that way.

The problem is when a user gives the post a rating, the PUT call is refused if the user updated the post recently.

Is there a way to force Ebean to ignore the version field in specific situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Please don't suggest I do this to solve the problem, I can't do it that way.*

LOL, nobody's gonna to suggest it to you :)

Custom statement should avoid updating the version:

```
SqlUpdate update = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("UPDATE post set likes = likes+1 where id = :id");
update.setParameter("id", post.id).execute();
```

(tested it, works as required)

Comment: Yeah, custom sql could do it but I have a system over inheritance in place and adding in custom sql everywhere is very intrusive and I'd like to avoid doing it if at all possible.

Comment: I'd suggest adding custom statemets only for things like likes counters

Comment: Well, after looking at the other options, this seemed to be the best way. So after some work, got it working like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach to using SqlUpdate in Ebean 4.x you can use 'stateless updates'. Note that for the counter = counter + 1 use case SqlUpdate is still a better fit.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(42);
customer.setName("Please update the name")
// customer.setVersion(2)   ... not setting the version property

// perform stateless update (and the version property was not set)
Ebean.update(customer);

// effectively results in:
update customer set name = 'Please update the name' where id = 42
```